# The velcro has come off/undone. Lemme stick it for you

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

A kid is wearing shoes with velcro. So it wasn't sticking so the parent said:

> It has **come off/come undone.** Lemme **stick** it for you.

And what about asking another person:

> Come on **stick** it back on! (Velcro)

So should "**come undone**" or "**come off**" be used? And what about "**stick**"?

And if someone "**unfastens**" the velcro, then what will be used by the other person to describe this?

> Why did you "**unfasten**" your velcro?

What will be a more natural way to express this?

Do they sound natural?

Comment: Let me, please, not lemme.

Answer (score 1):

I would **not** say

> Let me stick it for you.

I might say:

> Let me stick it (back) on for you.

I would be more likely to say

> Let (re)fasten it for you.

but that is a matter of style.

I would find any of "**come off**", "**come undone**", "**come unfastened**", or "**is unfastened**" to be acceptable. So

> The strap  has come undone. Let me refasten it for you.

or

> The strap is unfastened. Let me fix it for you.

or

> The strap has come loose. Let me stick it back on for you.

would all seem perfectly correct and natural to me.

I would add that I woulds never write "lemme" and even in hasty speech would be closer to "let me".

Answer (score 0):

A Velcro strap is closed using pressure.

Anyway, show laces are undone and can be done up. To do up shoe laces.

But here, "let me fix it for you" is best.

Why? Because Velcro doesn't have a verb that goes with it.

If the Velcro strap is not pushed down, one would fix it by pushing it down into place.

I guess one can say other things such as: Let me put it in place. Let me put it right.