# do we say "stick up the sandals" when we do up sandals by sticking?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

The above sandal has buckles, so we say "**buckle up the sandal**".

**But this sandal has no buckles.**

[image]

Since this sandal has no buckle, then

**What is the rub surface that we stick the strap on to do up the sandal called?**

and

**do we say "*stick up the sandals*" (for sandals that are similar to the one in the picture 2)?**

Comment: Related: [“Pull your band off first.”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/130458); [The velcro has come off/undone. Lemme stick it for you](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/209703); [Does the verb “unvelcro” exist or what can we use instead?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53969)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the rub surface that we stick the strap on to do up the sandal called?

This is commonly referred to as Velcro, which is a trademarked name. The generic term is "hook-and-loop fastener," but this phrase is widely seen as technical and may not be understood.

> do we say "stick up the sandals" (for sandals that are similar to the one in the picture 2)?

No, "sticking up" a person means to rob them at gunpoint, and "sticking up" an inanimate object suggests that you are attaching it to a wall or ceiling. It wouldn't be used to refer to this action.

Instead, we would probably say something like "fasten the sandal," or (perhaps) "close the sandal." You can also say "do up the straps" as suggested in your image.